# Como generar un PDF con una funcion DOMPDF desde una API?

Tags: laravel, api, dompdf

Utilizé **DomPDF** para mostrar, descargar, enviar por correo un PDF que creo y genero correctamente desde la web principal, hice el servicio de estas funciones para implementarlas en otra web que se relaciona con esta.
La cuestion es que cuando consumo la api e intento mostrar el PDF se muestra un string super largo con caracteres especiales , al retornarlo con la función "**gettype**" muestra "**string**" cuando deberia mostrar el PDF correctamente.
Cabe destacar que desde la web principal la funcion se ejecuta correctamente sin ningun problema, de igual forma con postman tambien funciona, solo desde mi codigo es que no se muestra correctamente.

> Controlador de la web secundaria que intenta mostrar el pdf

```
public function certifiedMuta($id)
{
    $option = 2;
    $view = Http::withToken($this->getToken())->withHeaders(['Content-Disposition' => 'attachment' ,'Accept' => 'application/pdf'])->get(env('API_URL').'pdf/certificado-recoleccion/'.$id.'/'.$option);
    return $view;
}
```

> Servicio de la pagina principal

```
public function pdf_collection_reaceico($id, $option)
{
    $reaceico = RegisterVisit::find($id);
    $email = $reaceico->schedule->getMutant->email;

    $pimpinas = VisitMaterials::where('register_visit_id', $id)->where('material_id', 4)->first();

    $pdf = app()->make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->getDomPDF()->setBasePath(realpath('paper'));
    $pdf->loadView('layouts.pdf.collection_reaceico', ['reaceico' => $reaceico, 'pimpina' => $pimpinas])
    ->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

    if ($option == 1) {
        return $pdf->stream('certificado_reaceico_'.$reaceico->schedule->getMutant->name.'.pdf');
    }
    else if ($option == 2) {
        return $pdf->download('certificado_reaceico_'.$reaceico->schedule->getMutant->name.'.pdf');
    }
    else if ($option == 3) {
        Mail::to($email)->send(new ReaceicoMail($reaceico, $pimpinas));
        return back()->withStatus(__('Correo enviado exitosamente'));
    }
    else
    {
        return back();
    }

}
```

**Adjunto imagen**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]